# Why do I get an Unbound value Error even though it works in the Terminal in Ocaml

Tags: error-handling, ocaml, record

There has to be a minor error in my code because it works in the VSC-Terminal but not in the editor but I do not understand what it could be,
**I get the Unbound value Error for the `avg_grade` and `get_grades` functions**

Let `studentlist` be a list which safes `student` records. Each student has a `(int*float)` grades-list which safes a numeration as a int and the actual grades as floats.

My aim is to calculate the average grade of a single student with the function `avg_grade`.
I call the single student-record with the age with the get_student function.

```
type student = {
  name : string;
  age : int;
  grades : (int*float) list;
}

let studentlist = 
  [ {name="alex"; age=7; grades=[(1,3.)]} ;
    {name="bianca"; age=6; grades=[(1, 2.); (2, 3.)]} ]

(* main-function to calculate the average *)
let avg_grade a lst = 
  try 
    grades_sum a lst /. length a lst 
  with 
    Not_found -> 0.0

(* function to add all the float-grades, 
   it calls the list with get_grades *)
let grades_sum a lst = 
  List.fold_left (fun i (_,b) -> i +. b) 0. (get_grades a lst)

(* calls the grades of a single record which is called per age *)  
let get_grades a lst = 
  (get_student a lst).grades

(*calls a single student-record*)
let get_student a lst = 
  List.find (fun {age;_} -> a = age) lst

(* computes the length of the given grades-list *)
let length a lst = 
  float_of_int (List.length (get_grades a lst))
```

Comment: What error exactly are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
let avg_grade a lst = try grades_sum a lst /. length a lst with Not_found -> 0.0
```

But `grades_sum` isn't defined until *after* that line of code, so you get:

```
Error: Unbound value grades_sum
```

---

Additionally, a style suggestion. The `|>` operator may be useful for cleaning up some of your code. For better understanding of how it works:

```
let (|>) x f = f x
```

This allows something like `f (g (h x))` to be written `h x |> g |> f`. Doing this lets us see that `h x` is being evaluated first. The result of that is sent to `g`, and then finally to `f`.

Both *do* the same thing, but the latter may be more *expressive* of what the code is doing.

You could use this to rewrite:

```
let length a lst = 
  float_of_int (List.length (get_grades a lst))
```

As:

```
let length a lst = 
  get_grades a lst |> List.length |> float_of_int
```